# validation polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a polymorphic address model which i use in several forms. i do simple validation in that model but it doesn't work. what am i doing wrong?

Address Model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street1, :street2, :city, state, :zip
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  validates_length_of :state, :maximun => 2, :too_long => "Field State is to long"

  validates_numericality_of :zip, :on => :create, :message => "Zip Code must be numeric!"
  validates_length_of :zip, :within => 5..9, :too_long => "Zip Code to long.", :too_short => "Zip Code to short"  
end

Location Model

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :account

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_length_of :name, :maximum =>80
end
```

Location Edit Form - for example

```
<% form_for [@account, @location] do |f| %>
    <table>
        <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
    </table>
    <%= f.submit("Update") %>
<% end %>
```

thanks for any help.
Ed

Answer (score 0):

What's the error? What validation isn't running?
Also, you could take a look at: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

Comment: there is no error. when i create or update it is not validating. for example in zip field i can type letters and it still saves the record without any errors.

Comment: Try adding :validate => true to the location model in the has_one relation with address